# How to include temporal correlation structure in a GAM with biannual counts

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive, generalized-additive-model

I have count data of a species and would like to analyze the population trend over the years.
The species was count twice a year (early summer and late summer --> column "season") for several years on different sites. The model I have set up is the following:

`gam(count ~ s(site, bs = "re") + s(year) + season, data=mydata, family = nb)`

If I want to include a correlation structure

`gamm(count ~ s(site, bs = "re") + s(year) + season, data=mydata, family = nb, correlation = corAR1(form=~year|site))`

I get an error since I have two observations for each year and site. The solutions I can think of are:

1. Limit the analysis to one season -> only one count per year and site
2. Sum the counts per year and site -> only one count per year and site

I don't like the first one since I use only half of my data but I also think that it might be the only way since I know that higher counts in early summer lead to higher counts in late summer - does this mean my data is not independent?

What is the best way to analyze this data?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I think you could just specify a variable that contains the time ordering, rather than `year` and nest that within `site`.

So you want a variable `time` (say) that is the integers `1, 2, 3, ..., T` in `site` 1, and again in `site` 2 and so on. This would be pretty straight forward to code in R if you have no missing time points in any of the sites. It needs to be coded (integers) in each `site` the same I think because you'll have the same correlation estimated for each `site` so we want time `1` in `site` A to match time `1` in `site` B.

Once you have that variable, the correlation argument would then be `corAR1(form = ~ time | site)`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @GavinSimpson, do the integers need to start over with each new day? For example, if Day 1 had 6 samples, its timestamp variable would be 1:6 (1st - 6th time stamp), Day 2 with 9 samples and timestamps would be 1:9, etc?

Comment: @Nate in `form = ~ x | y`, x should order the data within values of y, x must be unique within y, and x = j must be the same jth time point in each y.